# Sessions_End and StateServer Sessions mode

Tags: session-state

As we all know , `Session_End` event does not fire when session mode is set to `StateServer`.

But here is a problem ,that in a project I use this event to delete a record that assigned to the current logged in user that its sessions expired

Now I am looking for another way to replace it with this event.
Is there anyone out there to give me an idea about this stuff ?!!

thanks

Ali Foroughi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following article:

[ASP.NET HttpModule for handling session end with StateServer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S)